# Case when on json_array_elements in select statment

Tags: json, postgresql

`json_array_elements` return the NULL arrays and i must convert to Boolean arrays
How do it ?  I must do it in select statement , if it is must used case when?

Example -

```sql
CASE WHEN (
           json_array_elements(cards -> 'founders')
                                     ->>'num_founded_organizations'
          )::text::int::boolean 
       AS founder_of_startup
```

it returns the error

> ERROR:  argument of CASE/WHEN must not return a set

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 0):

Can put case when in insert or update statement:

```
               VALUES(
                ...,
                ...,
                ...,
                case when founder_of_startup is null then false else founder_of_startup end,
                ...,
                ...
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).